# How to terminate all threads reading from Pipe (NSPipe) related to Process (NSTask)?

Tags: xcode, multithreading, cocoa, appkit, nstask

I am writing a MacOS/Cocoa app that monitors a remote log file using a common recipe that launches a `Process` (formerly `NSTask`) instance on a background thread and reads `stdout` of the process via a `Pipe` (formally a `NSPipe`) as listed below:

```
class LogTail {
  var process : Process? = nil

  func dolog() {

    //
    // Run ssh fred@foo.org /usr/bin/tail -f /var/log.system.log
    // on a background thread and monitor it's stdout.
    //
    let processQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    processQueue.async {
       //
       // Create process and associated command.
       // 
       self.process = Process()
       process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/ssh"
       process.arguments = ["fred@foo.org",
                            "/usr/bin/tail", "-f",
                            "/var/log.system.log"]
       process.environment = [ ... ]

       //
       // Create pipe to read stdout of command as data is available
       //
       let pipe = Pipe()
       process.standardOutput = pipe
       let outHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
       outHandle.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
         if let string = String(data: pipe.availableData,
                                encoding: .utf8) {
            // write string to NSTextView on main thread
         }
       } 

       //
       // Launch process and block background thread 
       // until process complete.
       //
       process.launch()
       process.waitUntilExit()

       //
       // What do I do here to make sure all related
       // threads terminate?
       //
       outHandle.closeFile() // XXX
       outHandle.readabilityHandler = nil // XXX
   }
}
```

Everything works just dandy, but when the process quits (killed via `process.terminate`) I notice (via Xcode's Debug Navigator and the Console app) that there are multiple threads  consuming 180% or more of the CPU!?!

*Where is this CPU leak coming from?*

I threw in  `outHandle.closeFile()` (see code marked XXX above) and that reduced the CPU usage down to just a few percent but the threads still existed! What am I doing wrong or how do a make sure all the related threads terminate (I prefer graceful terminations i.e., threads body finish executing)!?

Some one posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713744/can-someone-help-me-spot-a-leak-in-this-nspipe-nsfilehandle-code?rq=1) almost 5 years ago!

**UPDATE:**

The documentation for [`NSFileHandle's readabilityHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilehandle/1412413-readabilityhandler) says:

> To stop reading the file or socket, set the value of this property to
>   nil. Doing so cancels the dispatch source and cleans up the file
>   handle’s structures appropriately.

so setting `outHandle.readabilityHandler = nil` seems to solve the problem too.

Even though I have seemingly solved the problem, I really don't understand where this massive CPU leak comes from -- very mysterious.